# how to perform excel open save and close operations through java program?

Tags: java, excel

I am using Apache POI library to update data in excel, which performs some calculations. Some formulas are not supported by POI library due to which need excel to perform these updates/calculations. But excel is not getting refreshed after updating(means its not performing recalculations).

Excel is getting refreshed if I open excel manually, it does recalculation.
Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using XSSF Workbook

Evaluate your cell formulaes with below code:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

Or in case you are using HSSF Workbook

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

In case you may want to explore more go [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)